# Print Error in Python 3.4

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error

Why am I getting a syntax error on the print function lines?
I've Tried it without the end=' ' in the brackets but still not working. I want to have all the print functions on one line.

```
#This program will convert a given amount
#of seconds into hours, minutes, seconds format

total_time = int(input("Number of Seconds"))
hours = int((total_time//(60*60)))
minutes = int(((total_time/60)-(hours*60)))
seconds = int((total_time-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60))

print('There are', end=' ')
print(hours, end=' ')
print('hours', end=' ')
print(minutes, end=' ')
print('minutes,',end=' ')
print('and', end=' ')
print(seconds, end=' ')
print('seconds', end=' ')
print('in', end=' ')
print(total_time, end=' ')
print('seconds', end=' ')
```

Comment: You may want to use an IDE/editor that can help you avoid such mistakes. I recommend picking up vi slowly while working with jetbrains' pycharm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren:

```
seconds = int((total_time-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60)) # <- missing closing
```

should be:

```
seconds = int((total_time-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60)))
```

FWIW often the error is on the line before what you see in the traceback